# mysqldump changes primary key to unique key?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

While attempting to dump and restore a WordPress database in MySQL, I noticed that `mysqldump` seems to be changing the `PRIMARY KEY` on several tables to a `UNIQUE KEY` instead. For example, this tables:

```
mysql> describe wp_yoast_seo_meta;
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| object_id           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| internal_link_count | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| incoming_link_count | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Is dumped as:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_yoast_seo_meta` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `internal_link_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `incoming_link_count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `object_id` (`object_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Notice the `object_id` field is used to create a `UNIQUE_KEY` index, instead of being set as the `PRIMARY KEY`. I'm not using any special options to `mysqldump` other than specifying the host name and user name.

How can I get `mysqldump` to include the primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MyISAM, there is no implementation difference between `PRIMARY` and `UNIQUE`.  (I don't know why it would do what it did.)

You should upgrade to InnoDB.